# How to set default category in Movable Type

Tags: movabletype

Is there a way to set the default category for each entry in Movable Type. I am using Movable Type version 5.12

I could not find any method for it. Is there any way or a plugin to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should try the [Default Categories](https://github.com/danwolfgang/mt-plugin-default-category) plugin by [Dan Wolfgang](http://danandsherree.com/) and see if it does what you need.

We've never implemented it for a customer, but Dan's an established developer with a good track record.  I haven't heard of any problems with the plugin recently.

Comment: I tried installing that plugin, but there are no installation instructions. So I am not very sure how/where to install it. I have tried both the methods mentioned on http://www.movabletype.org/documentation/administrator/plugins/. If you know how we can install this plugin that would be really helpful.

Comment: The standard location for installing plugins would be `~/cgi-bin/mt/plugins` where `~` is the absolute path to your hosting account.

For example, in some environments we work in where cPanel is installed on the hosting server, the full path would be `/home/myaccount/public_html/cgi-bin/mt/plugins/`.

Note that the contents of the p[ugins directory in the `mt-plugin-default-category` repo is what should be copied into the plugins directory.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Dan's 'Default Categories' plugin on both movable type v4.x and v5.x for a few media customers that needed to impose a specific category as default and I could confirm that the plugin works very well for both v4.x and v5.x.